# Liferay 6.2 Media Gallery

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

[image]

```html
<%--
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2000-2013 Liferay, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
 * Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
 * any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more
 * details.
 */
--%>

<%@ include file="/html/portlet/image_gallery_display/init.jsp" %>

<%
Folder folder = (Folder)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_FOLDER);

long defaultFolderId = GetterUtil.getLong(portletPreferences.getValue("rootFolderId", StringPool.BLANK), DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID);

long folderId = BeanParamUtil.getLong(folder, request, "folderId", defaultFolderId);

boolean defaultFolderView = false;

if ((folder == null) && (defaultFolderId != DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID)) {
 defaultFolderView = true;
}

if (defaultFolderView) {
 try {
  folder = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(folderId);
 }
 catch (NoSuchFolderException nsfe) {
  folderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;
 }
}

long repositoryId = scopeGroupId;

if (folder != null) {
 repositoryId = folder.getRepositoryId();
}

int status = WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED;

if (permissionChecker.isContentReviewer(user.getCompanyId(), scopeGroupId)) {
 status = WorkflowConstants.STATUS_ANY;
}

long portletDisplayDDMTemplateId = PortletDisplayTemplateUtil.getPortletDisplayTemplateDDMTemplateId(displayStyleGroupId, displayStyle);
%>

<c:choose>
 <c:when test="<%= portletDisplayDDMTemplateId > 0 %>">

  <%
  String[] mediaGalleryMimeTypes = DLUtil.getMediaGalleryMimeTypes(portletPreferences, renderRequest);

  List fileEntries = DLAppServiceUtil.getGroupFileEntries(scopeGroupId, 0, folderId, mediaGalleryMimeTypes, status, 0, SearchContainer.MAX_DELTA, null);
  %>

  <%= PortletDisplayTemplateUtil.renderDDMTemplate(pageContext, portletDisplayDDMTemplateId, fileEntries) %>
 </c:when>
 <c:otherwise>

  <%
  String topLink = ParamUtil.getString(request, "topLink", "home");

  long assetCategoryId = ParamUtil.getLong(request, "categoryId");
  String assetTagName = ParamUtil.getString(request, "tag");

  boolean useAssetEntryQuery = (assetCategoryId > 0) || Validator.isNotNull(assetTagName);

  PortletURL portletURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();

  portletURL.setParameter("struts_action", "/image_gallery_display/view");
  portletURL.setParameter("topLink", topLink);
  portletURL.setParameter("folderId", String.valueOf(folderId));

  request.setAttribute("view.jsp-folder", folder);

  request.setAttribute("view.jsp-defaultFolderId", String.valueOf(defaultFolderId));

  request.setAttribute("view.jsp-folderId", String.valueOf(folderId));

  request.setAttribute("view.jsp-repositoryId", String.valueOf(repositoryId));

  request.setAttribute("view.jsp-viewFolder", Boolean.TRUE.toString());

  request.setAttribute("view.jsp-useAssetEntryQuery", String.valueOf(useAssetEntryQuery));

  request.setAttribute("view.jsp-portletURL", portletURL);
  %>

  <portlet:actionURL var="undoTrashURL">
   <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_entry" />
   <portlet:param name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" value="<%= Constants.RESTORE %>" />
  </portlet:actionURL>

  <liferay-ui:trash-undo portletURL="<%= undoTrashURL %>" />

  <liferay-util:include page="/html/portlet/document_library/top_links.jsp" />

  <c:choose>
   <c:when test="<%= useAssetEntryQuery %>">
    <liferay-ui:categorization-filter
     assetType="images"
     portletURL="<%= portletURL %>"
    />

    <%
    SearchContainer searchContainer = new SearchContainer(renderRequest, null, null, "cur2", SearchContainer.DEFAULT_DELTA, portletURL, null, null);
    
    OrderByComparator orderByComparator = DLUtil.getRepositoryModelOrderByComparator("modifiedDate", "desc");
searchContainer.setOrderByComparator(orderByComparator);
    

    long[] classNameIds = {PortalUtil.getClassNameId(DLFileEntryConstants.getClassName()), PortalUtil.getClassNameId(DLFileShortcut.class.getName())};

    AssetEntryQuery assetEntryQuery = new AssetEntryQuery(classNameIds, searchContainer);

    assetEntryQuery.setEnablePermissions(true);
    assetEntryQuery.setExcludeZeroViewCount(false);

    int total = AssetEntryServiceUtil.getEntriesCount(assetEntryQuery);

    searchContainer.setTotal(total);

    List results = AssetEntryServiceUtil.getEntries(assetEntryQuery);

    searchContainer.setResults(results);

    String[] mediaGalleryMimeTypes = null;

    request.setAttribute("view.jsp-mediaGalleryMimeTypes", mediaGalleryMimeTypes);
    request.setAttribute("view.jsp-searchContainer", searchContainer);
    %>

    <liferay-util:include page="/html/portlet/image_gallery_display/view_images.jsp" />
   </c:when>
   <c:when test='<%= topLink.equals("home") %>'>
    <aui:row>
     <c:if test="<%= folder != null %>">
      <liferay-ui:header
       localizeTitle="<%= false %>"
       title="<%= folder.getName() %>"
      />
     </c:if>

     <%
     SearchContainer searchContainer = new SearchContainer(renderRequest, null, null, "cur2", SearchContainer.DEFAULT_DELTA, portletURL, null, null);

     String[] mediaGalleryMimeTypes = DLUtil.getMediaGalleryMimeTypes(portletPreferences, renderRequest);

     int foldersCount = DLAppServiceUtil.getFoldersCount(repositoryId, folderId, true);

     int total = DLAppServiceUtil.getFoldersAndFileEntriesAndFileShortcutsCount(repositoryId, folderId, status, mediaGalleryMimeTypes, true);

     int imagesCount = total - foldersCount;

     searchContainer.setTotal(total);

     List results = DLAppServiceUtil.getFoldersAndFileEntriesAndFileShortcuts(repositoryId, folderId, status, mediaGalleryMimeTypes, true, searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd(), searchContainer.getOrderByComparator());

     searchContainer.setResults(results);

     request.setAttribute("view.jsp-mediaGalleryMimeTypes", mediaGalleryMimeTypes);
     request.setAttribute("view.jsp-searchContainer", searchContainer);
     %>

     <aui:col cssClass="lfr-asset-column lfr-asset-column-details" width="<%= showFolderMenu ? 75 : 100 %>">
      <div id="<portlet:namespace />imageGalleryAssetInfo">
       <c:if test="<%= folder != null %>">
        <div class="lfr-asset-description">
         <%= HtmlUtil.escape(folder.getDescription()) %>
        </div>

        <div class="lfr-asset-metadata">
         <div class="lfr-asset-icon lfr-asset-date">
          <%= LanguageUtil.format(pageContext, "last-updated-x", dateFormatDate.format(folder.getModifiedDate())) %>
         </div>

         <div class="lfr-asset-icon lfr-asset-subfolders">
          <%= foldersCount %> <liferay-ui:message key='<%= (foldersCount == 1) ? "subfolder" : "subfolders" %>' />
         </div>

         <div class="lfr-asset-icon lfr-asset-items last">
          <%= imagesCount %> <liferay-ui:message key='<%= (imagesCount == 1) ? "image" : "images" %>' />
         </div>
        </div>

        <liferay-ui:custom-attributes-available className="<%= DLFolderConstants.getClassName() %>">
         <liferay-ui:custom-attribute-list
          className="<%= DLFolderConstants.getClassName() %>"
          classPK="<%= (folder != null) ? folder.getFolderId() : 0 %>"
          editable="<%= false %>"
          label="<%= true %>"
         />
        </liferay-ui:custom-attributes-available>
       </c:if>

       <liferay-util:include page="/html/portlet/image_gallery_display/view_images.jsp" />
      </div>
     </aui:col>

     <c:if test="<%= showFolderMenu %>">
      <aui:col cssClass="lfr-asset-column lfr-asset-column-actions" last="<%= true %>" width="<%= 25 %>">
       <div class="lfr-asset-summary">
        <liferay-ui:icon
         cssClass="lfr-asset-avatar"
         image='<%= "../file_system/large/" + ((total > 0) ? "folder_full_image" : "folder_empty") %>'
         message='<%= (folder != null) ? HtmlUtil.escape(folder.getName()) : LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "home") %>'
        />

        <div class="lfr-asset-name">
         <h4><%= (folder != null) ? HtmlUtil.escape(folder.getName()) : LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "home") %></h4>
        </div>
       </div>

       <%
       request.removeAttribute(WebKeys.SEARCH_CONTAINER_RESULT_ROW);
       %>

       <liferay-util:include page="/html/portlet/document_library/folder_action.jsp" />
      </aui:col>
     </c:if>
    </aui:row>

    <%
    if (folder != null) {
     IGUtil.addPortletBreadcrumbEntries(folder, request, renderResponse);

     if (!defaultFolderView && portletName.equals(PortletKeys.MEDIA_GALLERY_DISPLAY)) {
      PortalUtil.setPageSubtitle(folder.getName(), request);
      PortalUtil.setPageDescription(folder.getDescription(), request);
     }
    }
    %>

   </c:when>
   <c:when test='<%= topLink.equals("mine") || topLink.equals("recent") %>'>

    <%
    long groupImagesUserId = 0;

    if (topLink.equals("mine") && themeDisplay.isSignedIn()) {
     groupImagesUserId = user.getUserId();
    }

    SearchContainer searchContainer = new SearchContainer(renderRequest, null, null, SearchContainer.DEFAULT_CUR_PARAM, SearchContainer.DEFAULT_DELTA, portletURL, null, null);

    String[] mediaGalleryMimeTypes = DLUtil.getMediaGalleryMimeTypes(portletPreferences, renderRequest);

    int total = DLAppServiceUtil.getGroupFileEntriesCount(repositoryId, groupImagesUserId, defaultFolderId, mediaGalleryMimeTypes, status);

    searchContainer.setTotal(total);

    List results = DLAppServiceUtil.getGroupFileEntries(repositoryId, groupImagesUserId, defaultFolderId, mediaGalleryMimeTypes, status, searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd(), searchContainer.getOrderByComparator());

    searchContainer.setResults(results);

    request.setAttribute("view.jsp-mediaGalleryMimeTypes", mediaGalleryMimeTypes);
    request.setAttribute("view.jsp-searchContainer", searchContainer);
    %>

    <aui:row>
     <liferay-ui:header
      title="<%= topLink %>"
     />

     <liferay-util:include page="/html/portlet/image_gallery_display/view_images.jsp" />
    </aui:row>

    <%
    PortalUtil.addPortletBreadcrumbEntry(request, LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, topLink), currentURL);

    PortalUtil.setPageSubtitle(LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, topLink), request);
    %>

   </c:when>
  </c:choose>
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

i m using Liferay 6.2 and using Media Gallery Portlet to display the images which is placed in Multiple folders. i have multiple folders which contain multiple images but the folders are arranged according to alphabetical order but my requirement is to arrange the folders which are recently updated (i,e the recently updated folder must come at the top) so can anybody please provide solution how to achieve this.

thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi the above code is view.jsp after adding OrderByComparator orderByComparator =
    DLUtil.getRepositoryModelOrderByComparator("modifiedDate", "desc");
searchContainer.setOrderByComparator(orderByComparator);         but there is no change in my media gallery portlet. it still shows in alphabetical order. Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Does your file get deployed properly. I have this in working form in ext environment. Can you try adding these two lines directly in container (tomcat) file? Just to make sure, the required change is working or it.

Comment: Hi i have added those 2 lines directly under \html\portlet\image_gallery_display\view.jsp and restarted the server but nothing is reflecting ...please provide solution for this issue..

Comment: Do you observe any crashing?

Comment: no i don't find any crashing

Comment: [***Snaps***](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvoVz2KQZq3KgzpKdyjFM0k1poaN) : This is what I have implemented and being used.

Comment: Have you added new image / folder for the testing?

Comment: Hi after i make changes as below suggested in init.jsp , configuration.jsp , view.jsp ...in  Media Gallery Configuration page under setup tab is empty..please check the attachment for image

Comment: Did you restart the tomcat?

Comment: yes after code updation i have restarted the tomcat

Comment: What is the error appearing in the console?

Comment: there is no error but setup tab configuration is not displayed . complete setup tab under configuration is empty.

Comment: Last thing, can you application accessed remotely?

Comment: sorry it can't be accessed remotely

Comment: Can you send me these files? So that I can test it out locally.

Comment: can i have your mail id?

Comment: parkash-kumar@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Over-ride `view.jsp` of `/html/portlet/image_gallery_display` by either hook or ext and add following two lines below the initialization of `SearchContainer` object at about line# 115:

```
OrderByComparator orderByComparator =
    DLUtil.getRepositoryModelOrderByComparator("modifiedDate", "desc");
searchContainer.setOrderByComparator(orderByComparator);
```

This will order your Media Gallery's folders and images descending by modified date.

**Update:**
If you want to control this behavior from preferences, then:

> 1. Declare and initialize these properties in `init.jsp`:

```
String sortByCol = portletPreferences.getValue("sortByCol", "title");
String sortByOrder = portletPreferences.getValue("sortByOrder", "desc");
```

> 2. Add following drill-downs for value selection in
>      `configuration.jsp`:

```
<div class="aui-column left-selector-column">
    <aui:select label="Sort By" name="preferences--sortByCol--">
        <aui:option label="Title" value="title"
            selected="<%= sortByCol.equals("title") %>" />
        <aui:option label="Create Date" value="creationDate"
            selected="<%= sortByCol.equals("creationDate") %>"/>
        <aui:option label="Modified Date" value="modifiedDate"
            selected="<%= sortByCol.equals("modifiedDate") %>" />
    </aui:select>
</div>

<div class="aui-column right-selector-column">
    <aui:select label="Order" name="preferences--sortByOrder--">
        <aui:option label="Ascending" value="asc"
            selected="<%= sortByOrder.equals("asc") %>"/>
        <aui:option label="Descending" value="desc"
            selected="<%= sortByOrder.equals("desc") %>"/>
    </aui:select>
</div>
```

> 3. Add these two lines in `view.jsp` below the
>      initialization of SearchContainer:

```
OrderByComparator orderByComparator =
    DLUtil.getRepositoryModelOrderByComparator(sortByCol, sortByOrder);
searchContainer.setOrderByComparator(orderByComparator);
```

Comment: Do not use [ext plugin](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/advanced-customization-with-ext-plugins) for that! It's only meant to be used in situations where you have absolutely no other options. Go with [jsp hook plugin](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-web-resources). Alternatively (if the portlet supports it) you could use [ADT](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-application-display-templates)